# Cómo puedo solucionar redundancia cíclica en mi disco duro sin chkdsk?

Tags: cmd, memoria, hardware, usb

Tengo un disco duro externo que cuando lo conecto funciona, la luz del disco parpadea como siempre y la computadora detecta que se ha conectado una usb. Lamentablemente el disco duro no tiene asignado un volumen, por lo que no aparece como una unidad en "este equipo" en windows, sin embargo con diskpart lo detecta.

Cuando abro el administrador de discos lo detecta e incluso me da la opción de inicializarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando le doy a aceptar aparece lo siguiente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se que hay una forma de corregir el problema con chkdsk pero para usarlo debo especificale el volumen y al disco no tiene un volumen en el sistema.  Alguna sugerencia o herramienta para solucionar el problema.

Comment: Intentaste cambiarlo de GPT a MBR? O ya es MBR?

Comment: El disco parece que no tiene particiones lógicas. Sin particion Windows no puede asignar letras de volumen

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no trata de programación tal como se establece en el [help/on-topic]